# Issue using template alias nested in object passed to template

Tags: c++, templates

I having a problem trying to get template to work with an alias nested in one of its arguments. It works if I make an alias in the template itself and use that as an argument to another template. I would like to use it without doing this so that it can be passed down through inheritance to another template.

I think my problem has something to do with the compiler not knowing what the template arguments are and says the template argument is invalid, but I don't know if there is a way to correct this without using the extra alias.

```
template< template<typename>class T >
struct TemplateWrapper {
    template<typename U>
    using type = T<U>;
};

template<typename T>
struct TemplateTester{
    template<typename U>
    using type = typename T::template type<U>; //This works fine
    TemplateWrapper<type> test; //This works fine

    TemplateWrapper< typename T::template type > test2; //error: template argument 1 is invalid
};
```

I'm using MinGW with GCC 4.7.1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `TemplateWrapper< T::template type >`

Comment: @jrok: Ohai to you :)

Comment: YEEESSS! Thank you Andy!